# Integer solutions to $2m^4 = n^4 + 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The problem looks deceptively simple. I know of solutions to variations of that such as $m^4 = 2n^4 + 1$. I have tried various approaches but didnt get far and so not worth reproducing it here.

To be clear, I am looking for integer solutions to $2m^4 = n^4 + 1$.

Thanks

Comment: do you know any solution for this?

Comment: I seem to recall an article of Kedlaya dealing with the intersections of linear recurring sequences. In this case we have to intersect the sequence of solutions of a Pell equation with the set of squares.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Is [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1998-67-222/S0025-5718-98-00918-1/home.html) it? I think there is an unsolved question regarding simultaneous pell equations, this could be a nice tool to solve them without resorting to elliptic curves.

Answer (score 4):

Ljunggren has proved that the Diophantine equation $2m^4=n^2+1$ has only two (positive) integral solutions, namely $(1,1)$ and $(13,239)$. Since $(13,239)$ is not a solution to the equation of the question, the only positive solution for $2m^4=n^4+1$ is $(1,1)$; so the only integral solutions are $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$.

References: L. J. Mordell, The Diophantine equation $y^2 = Dx^4 +1$, J. London Math. Soc. 39 (1964), 161-164.

Hua: [A new solution of the Diophantine equation $x^2+1=2y^4$](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022314X84710523/1-s2.0-S0022314X84710523-main.pdf?_tid=6721dfd4-0c8c-11e7-babc-00000aacb360&acdnat=1489918462_7331d80a623cbb57c792c8a4cdf50307).

Comment: I don't have access to that paper. I couldn't find it on the web. Do you know of a site where I can read the proof? Thank

Comment: Try [this link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243002779_Simplifying_the_solution_of_Ljunggren%27s_equation_X212Y4); it is also called *Ljunggren's equation*. There are several other links (google it!)

Comment: It's called Ljunggren's equation because Ljunggren proved this. Mordell did not.

Comment: @MikeBennett Thank you very much, I have added a paper with references.

Comment: I can rewrite original problem as $2m^2 - \lfloor{m\sqrt{2}}\rfloor^2 = 1$ and the only solutions to this are (1,1) or (169, 239). Note $239 = \lfloor169 * \sqrt2\rfloor$). Just interesting that 169 satisfies this.

Answer (score 1):

It has been shown (although the general proof is difficult, being related to that of Fermat's Last Theorem) that there are no non-trivial solutions of $x^n + y^n = 2z^n$ for *any* $n \geq 3$ ([Darmon & Merel 2001](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/uploads//loic.merel//files/winding.pdf) pp 2 & 24). Hence, putting $n=4$ and $y=1$ (and re-lettering), there are no solutions of $2m^4=n^4+1$ other than $(\pm1,\pm1)$.

Comment: You can find online proof [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/descent.pdf), page 9 co3.16

Comment: @i9Fn  Yes, the proof in Conrad for the 4th power case is much simpler.  But the Darmon & Merel result is much more general and seems to be not too well-known.

Comment: Oops I didn't notice you linked to the proof. Speaking of underappreciated proofs, you can also do it with results on squares in Lucas sequences.